# How do I center TabPanel in React material UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to create a list of articles with switching to a list of other entities in React + material UI. But I faced some problems, namely, I can't center `Card`, which displays an article in the way, that will correspond to centered `Tabs`. So, I get something like this:

[image: How it looks now]

Can anyone help me to make it to look symmetric?

I want the `Card` to be centered in the same way, the `Tabs` are.

`TabsMenu.js`, which itself is displayed:

```js
import React from "react";
import {makeStyles} from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Tabs from "@material-ui/core/Tabs";
import Tab from "@material-ui/core/Tab";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import * as PropTypes from "prop-types";
import ArticlesList from "./ArticlesList";

function TabPanel(props) {
    const {children, value, index, ...other} = props;
    return (
        <div
            role="tabpanel"
            hidden={value !== index}
            id={`simple-tab-${index}`}
            aria-labelledby={`simple-tab-${index}`}
            {...other}
        >
            {value === index && (
                <Box p={3}>
                    <Typography>{children}</Typography>
                </Box>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}

TabPanel.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node,
    index: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
    value: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
};

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    root: {
        flexGrow: 1,
    },
    tabpanel: {
        marginLeft: "auto"
    }
});

function a11yProps(index) {
    return {
        id: `simple-tab-${index}`,
        'aria-controls': `simple-tabpanel-${index}`,
    };
}

export default function CenteredTabs(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
    const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
        setValue(newValue);
    }
    return (

        <Paper className={classes.root}>
            <article>
                <Tabs
                    value={value}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    indicatorColor="primary"
                    textColor="primary"
                    centered
                >

                    <Tab label="Articles" {...a11yProps(0)}/>
                    <Tab label="News" {...a11yProps(1)}/>
                    <Tab label="Authors" {...a11yProps(2)}/>
                </Tabs>
                <TabPanel value={value} index={0} className={classes.tabpanel}>

                    <ArticlesList articles={[{
                        imageSrc: "https://frontendmasters.com/static-assets/learn/og-learning-path-react.jpg",
                        authorImageSrc: "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/--OlyHl449xI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ACevoQNk7ZZElQ_vKIQT_6d4HZw_wN3Qxg/mo/photo.jpg?sz=64",
                        authorName: "Denis Ivanenko",
                        dateTime: "2017-02-14",
                        imageAlt: "Article Image",
                        title: "Test title",
                        subtitle: "Test subtitle"
                    }]}/>

                </TabPanel>
                <TabPanel value={value} index={1} className={classes.tabpanel}>
                    Item Two
                </TabPanel>
                <TabPanel value={value} index={2} className={classes.tabpanel}>
                    Item Three
                </TabPanel>
            </article>
        </Paper>

    );
}
```

`ArticlesList.js`, which is used in `TabsMenu.js`

```js
import React from 'react';
import {makeStyles} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ArticleCard from "./ArticleCard";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';


const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        width: '100%',
        maxWidth: 360,
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    },
}));


export default function ArticlesList(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className={classes.root}>
                <Grid container
                      spacing={0}
                      direction="column"
                      alignItems="center"
                      justify="center"
                      style={{minHeight: '100vh'}}>
                    <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <Box width={"150%"}>

                            <List component="nav" aria-label="secondary mailbox folders">

                                <ArticleCard title={"Introducing \"Dead Simple Python\"\n"}
                                             text={"Ever spent three hours trying to find that bit of knowledge that everyone seemed to have but you?\n" +
                                             "\n" +
                                             "As a self-trained Python developer, I've sometimes found myself stuck in that knowledge crater, between tutorials far simpler than real life, and articles more advanced than I could comprehend. Even the documentation felt like a firehose of information, making it nearly impossible to find the one basic thing I needed to know.\n" +
                                             "\n" +
                                             "In this series, I'll be exploring a few of these topics, in a way that hopefully makes them dead simple!\n" +
                                             "\n" +
                                             "Intended Audience\n" +
                                             "While programmers at all experience levels may find this series useful, I'm specifically targeting Python novices. I am assuming, however, that you have a very basic understanding of programming. The coding topics especially will be more focused on the Python way of doing things, not on the underlying generic concept.\n" +
                                             "\n" +
                                             "With that said, if you're an intermediate-level Python developer, you may still find it helpful to follow along with the series. Although I've been working with Python for nearly eight years, some of these topics didn't really \"click\" for me until recent years. These are the explanations I wish I'd had!\n" +
                                             "\n" +
                                             "What You Won't Find Here\n" +
                                             "All of the topics I'm discussing here go much, much deeper. However, I don't want to muddy the waters, so I'll be omitting a considerable amount of detail. Once you're comfortable with a topic, and have done it a few times yourself, I recommend going back and reading through the official Python documentation on the topic.\n" +
                                             "\n" +
                                             "A Note on Python Versions\n" +
                                             "The official end-of-life for Python 2 is rapidly approaching, so you should learn and begin using Python 3 as soon as possible! This entire series is geared towards Python 3, with a bias towards 3.6 and 3.7, except as otherwise noted.\n" +
                                             "\n" +
                                             "Edits\n" +
                                             "The articles in this series are frequently being reviewed by my fellow Python experts, and by the Dev community at large. I will expand and revise accordingly. Always check the edit timestamp at the top of the article.\n" +
                                             "\n" +
                                             "Roadmap\n" +
                                             "The current series plan is below. Please note, I may rearrange, add, or remove planned sections."}
                                             imageSrc={"https://insights.dice.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/shutterstock_315465929.jpg"}
                                             authorImageSrc={"https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/--OlyHl449xI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ACevoQNk7ZZElQ_vKIQT_6d4HZw_wN3Qxg/mo/photo.jpg?sz=64"}
                                             authorName={"Denis Ivanenko"}/>
                            </List>
                        </Box>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

`ArticleCard.js`

```js
import React from "react";
import {red} from '@material-ui/core/colors';
import makeStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/makeStyles";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardHeader from "@material-ui/core/CardHeader";
import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import CardMedia from "@material-ui/core/CardMedia";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import CardActions from "@material-ui/core/CardActions";
import clsx from "clsx";
import FavoriteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Favorite';
import ShareIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Share';
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        width:"155%",
        gridColumn: "2/span 7"
    },
    media: {
        height: 0,
        paddingTop: '56.25%',
    },
    expand: {
        transform: 'rotate(0deg)',
        marginLeft: 'auto',
        transition: theme.transitions.create('transform', {
            duration: theme.transitions.duration.shortest,
        }),
    },

    avatar: {
        backgroundColor: red[500],
    },
}));
export default function ArticleCard(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [expanded] = React.useState(false);

    const title = props.title;
    const date = props.dateTime;
    const imageSrc = props.imageSrc;
    const imageAlt = props.imageAlt;
    const previewText = props.text.substring(0,158)+"...";

    return (
        <Card className={classes.root}>
            <CardHeader
                avatar={
                    <Avatar aria-label="recipe" className={classes.avatar}>
                        <img src={props.authorImageSrc} alt={props.authorName}/>
                    </Avatar>
                }
                title={title}
                subheader={date}
            />
            <CardMedia
                className={classes.media}
                image={imageSrc}
                title={imageAlt}
            />
            <CardContent>
                <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
                    {previewText}
                </Typography>
            </CardContent>
            <CardActions disableSpacing>
                <IconButton aria-label="add to favorites">
                    <FavoriteIcon/>
                </IconButton>
                <IconButton aria-label="share">
                    <ShareIcon/>
                </IconButton>
                <Button
                    className={clsx(classes.expand, {
                        [classes.expandOpen]: expanded,
                    })}
                    aria-expanded={expanded}
                    aria-label="show more"
                    href={"/article"}
                >
                    Read More
                </Button>
            </CardActions>
        </Card>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has got nothing to do with material-ui, 
you've applied marginLeft: auto, which will not apply marginRight: auto, so it would not be center aligned

you should add marginRight: auto, as well to center it.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
    root: {
        flexGrow: 1,
    },
    tabpanel: {

        marginLeft: "auto",
        marginRight: "auto"

    }
});
```